# Attach application to server in New Relic

Tags: newrelic

I have one server running multiple node.js applications.
The monitor tool is installed on the server and each applications are monitored individually.
I would like to attach my applications to the server to see them in the apps section of my server dashboard.

Currently it displays :

> This server isn't hosting any apps that report to New Relic

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the instructions on the New Relic Node.js Agent Github?

https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic#getting-started

If you have followed the steps to install the agent, but it still won't report, you might want to open a support ticket at https://support.newrelic.com .

Answer (score 0):

The link between Server Monitoring instances and APM apps depends on the hostname. If you change the host name used by the Server Monitor for reporting purposes the linkage won't work anymore.

See this [post in the NewRelic forum](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/application-is-not-linked-to-server/8304/2?u=eddie).